# Encode in QRCode using ZXING

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to encode a String in QR Code wusing ZXING library. this is the lines of code corresponding to this :

```
Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", "TEXT_TYPE");
            intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA","HELLO WORLD");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });
}
```

After clicking on the button i have a "force close"

After looking in some websites, we say that it works just with these lines. unfortunately, it isnt for me.

PLEASE Can you give some advices to make it working. OR if you have other way to integrate a QRCode generator to my ANDROID App it will be great too.

Comment: do you have barcode scanner installed on the device you are using?

Comment: Do you use the emulator or a real device?

Comment: Is Zxing App is installed on device? If not then first install it from PlayStore.

Comment: i'm using the emulator and i don't have a barcode scanner on it

Comment: i doesnt work even on android device

Answer (score 4):

Enzo, this is another way to get it working, try this:

```
private void encode(String uniqueID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         BarcodeFormat barcodeFormat = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;

            int width0 = 500;
            int height0 = 500;

            int colorBack = 0xFF000000;
            int colorFront = 0xFFFFFFFF;

            QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
            try
            {
                EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object> hint = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
                hint.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");
                BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(uniqueID, barcodeFormat, width0, height0, hint);
                int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
                int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
                int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    int offset = y * width;
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {

                        pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? colorBack : colorFront;
                    }
                }

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
                ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.qrCode);
                imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (WriterException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Comment: what are the values of `colorBack` and `colorFront` variables?

Comment: int colorBack = 0xFF000000;
int colorFront = 0xFFFFFFFF;

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
```

identifies the **Activity** you are calling with the Intent. In order for it to work that Activity must exist on the device. If you haven't implemented the Activity inside your project (that is, there is no class `ENCODE` inside your `com.google.zxing.client.android` package) then you will be calling an external application from yours. If there are no applications on the device/emulator that respond to the broadcast for `com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE` then you are **not going to get anywhere** with this solution.

You either need to install an application that will respond to `com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE` or find another way to do it.

It is possible to **generate the barcode yourself** using *zxing libraries* within your application.  Have a look at the project [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list) at Google Code for some downloads. This will remove your dependancy on an external application existing, providing a more thorough solution.

Comment: thx for your answer. you are right after installing the zxing app on my device it start working. 

For scanning i ve tried with these lines of code :


 Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
 intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
 startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

and it works for scanning a qrcode without having the zxing app on my device. 

Now im developping an app which must generate a qrcode containing some information. so if theres a way to do it without need to call the zxing app it will be better for me

Answer (score -1):

Rather than Zxing library you are also able to get the string from QRCode by using intents as below :

```
try {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); // "PRODUCT_MODE for bar codes
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            } catch (Exception e) {    
                Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
                Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,marketUri);
                startActivity(marketIntent);
            }
```

And on activity result as below :

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                Log.v("MESSAGE: ", contents);
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity2.this,MainActivity3.class);
                Bundle b3= new Bundle();
                b3.putString("content",contents);
                in.putExtras(b3);   
                startActivity(in);    

            }
        }
    }
```

It may be helpful for you.

Thank You.